# Problem importing Bezier curve coordinates in Matlab from .svg

Tags: matlab, svg, bezier, curve, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to draw Bezier curves from an .svg file using Matlab.

I've opened the .svg in a text editor. One of the lines I'm trying to draw is this one: `<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M117.125,310.375c0-77.729,80.738-140.625,180.515-140.625"/>`

If I understand things correctly, the start point is (x , y) (117.125 , 310.375), the first control point is (0 , -77.729), the second control point is (80.738 , -140.625) and the end point is (180.515 , -140.625). However this doesn't seem to be correct as the output I get is far from the actual curve.

How it looks:
[image: matlab output]

How it's supposed to look:

[image: Web browser output]

The start and end points are all right, but the control points seem wrong... Matlab draws the correct points, I've checked them (the axis may look a bit weird but it's correct)

I'm using the code from Mathworks (https://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2014/10/13/bezier-curves/). It needs the start point pt1, the control points pt2 and pt3 and the end point pt4.

The code works, the problem seems to lie with the coordinates of the points. 
I've tried entering the coordinates above in an online .svg editor (it only supports integers so every coordinate is positive here, the control points shouldn't 'pull' the curve that much but the output is the same as the one obtained with MatLab): http://www.useragentman.com/tests/textpath/bezier-curve-construction-set.html#path=M%20297%2C%20169%20C%2058%2C%200%2C%2098%2C%2077%2C%2098%2C%20192&imageURL=http://www.useragentman.com/tests/textpath/images/grid.png

Here is the entire file, created with Illustrator CS6:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="116.083" y1="608.292" x2="117.125" y2="310.375"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M117.125,310.375c0-77.729,80.738-140.625,180.515-140.625"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.64,169.75c58.959,0,98.652,77.535,98.652,192.708"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="396.292" y1="362.458" x2="387.958" y2="653.083"/>
</svg>
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me with this. I'm new to .svg

Comment: I accidentally gave the wrong matlab graph, so the start and end points don't match the ones in my post. Sorry about that.

Comment: Matlab graph image updated. Problem is still there though.

Comment: I apologise in advance for being a little testy with you, but we see a lot of questions like this.  Before you went to the effort of making your screenshots and compiling this post, did you consider reading the SVG specification? If you had, you would have saved a lot of time. It has a large section on how [path definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-paths) work.. When you read that section, the answer to why your bezier is not working will become almost immediately apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paul LeBeau for the link. It turns out ".svg"s are case sensitive and that a C is not a c... You learn things every day. The website I looked at for help before I posted didn't mention this.

2, 3 and 4 are all relative to 1 in this case. I added a few lines of code to my script so that 2 = 1 + 2relative, 3 = 1 + 3relative and 4 = 1 + 4relative, and it works!

[image: Finished test piece]

Now I can finally clean up my code to do both the lines and the paths at the same time and draw my racing line.

NB: I know the points are reversed for the purple curve. This is due to Illustrator not being able to do a curve "the other way round" without switching the points...

Comment: If the website you looked at didn't mention that, that's _a huge oversight_ and you should contact the owner to fix that. SVG pathing instructions are pretty well documented all over the place, and that case difference is _crucial_ to writing manageable path instructions. Also note that you don't need 10 rep to use the normal markdown image syntax. Just upload your image to any site that allows hotlinking (like imgur.com) and then use `![alt text](url)` instead of trying to drag and drop images.